# How do you fix a namespace conflict with a third-party gem on your Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to use [Nunemaker's twitter gem](https://github.com/jnunemaker/twitter) for my Rails project but I already have a model/controller called Twitter and this conflicts with the Twitter gem.

Can someone please advise how I can namespace the Twitter gem to something else? What's the best way to handle this for my Rails app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to namespace the gem because that would break your app if you ever update the gem ([About monkeypatching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkeypatch)).

Better change the name of your controller, or namespace your controller. This is the better approach and less time-consuming.